# Insert to H2 database from a csv file with a decimal column and a bigdecimal JPA attribute, Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, csv, h2

I want to insert data into a h2 table that contains a `decimal(13, 4)` column from a csv file but I'm getting the following error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException at ScriptUtils.java:622
        Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException at DbException.java:457
            Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException at BigDecimal.java:577
```

This is the csv file

```
username,name,grupo,amount,percentage
MYUSER,CLIENT NAME,THE GROUP,30545000,0.093438569266185,
```

this is my table

```
create table my_table
(
    mytable_id integer     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user                   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    name            varchar(300)   DEFAULT NULL,
    grupo         varchar(300)   DEFAULT NULL,
    amount                 DECIMAL(13, 4) DEFAULT NULL,
    percentage    decimal(5, 2)  DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (mytable_id)
);
```

and this is my JPA entity class

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class CreditLineSummaryJPA {

@Id
@Column(name = "mytable_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long mytableId;

@Column(name = "user")
private String user;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "grupo")
private String grupo;

@Column(name = "amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@Column(name = "percentage")
private double userPercentage;

}
```

and this is the sql statement to insert from a csv file

```
    INSERT INTO my_table(user, name, the_group, amount, user_percentage)
SELECT "username", "name", "grupo", CONVERT("amount", decimal(13, 4)),
CONVERT ("percentage", decimal(5, 2))
FROM CSVREAD( 'myFile.csv', 'charset=UTF-8');
```

and this returns the following error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException at ScriptUtils.java:622
        Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException at DbException.java:457
            Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException at BigDecimal.java:577
```

***EDIT***
After using double quotes the error now is that it says

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "username" not found; SQL statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter of `CSVREAD` is a list of column names:
https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread

It should be `NULL` in your case:

```
CSVREAD('myFile.csv', NULL, 'charset=UTF-8')
```

Column names without spaces from CSV are normally converted to upper case (but it depends on database settings), so if you want to quote them, you need to write them in upper case (`"USERNAME"` etc.) or you can write them without quotes:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(user, name, grupo, amount, percentage)
SELECT username, name, grupo, CAST(amount AS decimal(13, 4)),
CAST(percentage AS decimal(5, 2))
FROM CSVREAD('myFile.csv', NULL, 'charset=UTF-8');
```

Few other notes.

1. Don't use `CONVERT`, it's a part of JDBC, but it isn't reliable at all and in H2 its behavior also depends on compatibility mode. Use a `CAST` specification, it is a part of the SQL Standard.
2. CAST specifications (or `CONVERT` functions) may be removed in this specific case, the `INSERT` statement will convert all values to data types of columns by itself.
3. `DEFAULT NULL` has no meaning; if value is not specified, it will be inserted as `NULL` automatically without any additional clauses. `DEFAULT NULL` is not an antonym for `NOT NULL`, `DEFAULT` is not related with presence or absence of `NOT NULL` constraint in any way.
4. Use `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` in recent versions of H2 **if you don't use MySQL compatibility mode**. `AUTO_INCREMENT` is a legacy non-standard and non-portable syntax, in H2 it should only be used in this compatibility mode.